# Microsoft Sync Framework scenario

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, data-synchronization

I have a following scenario and I am using Microsoft Sync framework for synchronization of the data.

I have a central server and two clients. The server is an aggregator of data from both clients.
The clients also synchronize between themselves. The syncs are done periodically and it can be that any client is not present in a certain moment in time.

So the problem that I have is:
Some data gets created on my client1 and it's synchronized to the server.
After a while my client goes offline from the server and gets in touch with client2.
They synchronize the data that was created at the client1 so after that client2 also contains that data.
And then client2 at some point in time gets in touch with the server and tries to synchronize.
Since the server already has the data that client1 created but it's obviously not aware that client2 has that same data so when I try to synchronize each entry is recognized as a Data conflict and an ApplyChangeFailed event is thrown. The sync framework manages to resolve this and the further syncs with the client2 are ok but my problem is that this takes a lot of time even for few thousand entries.

My question is: Is there a way to resolve this situation so that the sync framework doesn't even try to synchronize this data in the first place? Client1 could tell the Client2 during their sync that this data is already synchronized to the server and that it shouldn't be synchronized again.
Is there a functionality in Sync framework that does something like this?

Comment: Sync Fx should be able to handle the peer-to-peer scenario and should actually detect that data has been received by a replica from another peer. are you sure you're synching the same scope across peers?

Comment: I am actually not using the same scope to sync server and clients as I use to sync between clients. But these scopes overlap in some tables.

Comment: the information of what has been synched is stored per scope. what the other scope has synched, the other scope has no idea.

Comment: So I just need to make the scopes not contain same tables but use one scope to synchronize the common data. Thanks a lot for the help!